# Using __getattr__, how can I see if a value is set or get?

Tags: python

Looking at the following python3.3 code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['param'] = {'example': 10}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._param.keys():
            return self._param[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self._param.keys():
            self.__dict__['param'][name] = value
        else:
            raise AttributeError(name)



test = Test()

print(test.example)
test.example = 20
print(test.example)
```

the method `__getattr__` is used to get an instance a variable stored in the instantiated class. Is it possible to distinguish if a call to `__getattr__` is made to get a value or to set it?

If not, how can I adjust the code so whenever `__getattr__` (or something else) is called to *change* a value in my dict `_params`, I can set or flag or anything. I want to be able to set a flag when a value is changed. If a value is just read, no flag must be set.

Another possibility is to 'prevent' setting values like in the given example.

Comment: To set a value Python uses a different method: [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)

Comment: The 'naive' implementation give me a recursion error. So could you provide a code snippet on how to do it correctly?

Comment: Read the linked documentation.(Also get rid of the `.keys()` call, it is not required)

Comment: I think I implemented the code according to the documentation, but I still get infinite recursions. But I do not see an obvious problem now.

Comment: @Alex You're using `param` in some places, and `_param` in others. Fix that and you'll be good.

Comment: My bad... Works now! Thanks

Comment: That helped! The key point is that reads from class members other than __dict__ invoke the same __getattr__ and cause infinite recursion. Saving this to __dict__ does not trigger these. So I implemented sort of C struct class with dynamic fields on top of python dict.